# Submitting dynamic values to mySQL db

Tags: javascript, php

I have put together a test form for dynamic fields, I am having trouble with depositing the values into my database, I'm pretty sure the error is in syntax. Especially because as is the webpage doesn't even work, until I remove my PHP code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    /// Variables
    var html ='<p /><div>Make: <input type="TEXT" name="childmake[]" id="make" />Model: <input type="TEXT" name="model[]" id="childmodel" />Serials: <input type="TEXT" name="[]serials" id="childserials"/><a href="#" id="remove">X</a></div>';
    var maxRows = 20;
    var x = 1;

    /// Rows

    $("#add").click(function(e){
        if (x <= maxRows){

        $("#container").append(html);

        x++;
        }
    });
    /// Remove Rows
    $("#container").on('click','#remove', function(e){



        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;

    });


});

</script>
</head>

<form method="POST">
<div id="container">
Make: <input type="TEXT" name="make[]" id="make" />
Model: <input type="TEXT" name="model[]" id="model" />
Serials: <input type="TEXT" name="serials[]" id="serials"/>
<a href="#" id="add">Add More</a>

</div>
<p />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>


<?php
//placeholder
$output = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $make = $_POST['make'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $serials = $_POST['serials'];
    $databasename="jos_trip_detail"
    $mysql = mysql_connect('server','user','pass');
    $db = mysql_select_db($databasename);


    for($i=0; $i<count($make); $i++){


        if($make[$i]!="" && $model[$i]!="" && $serials[$i]!="")
        {

            mysql_query("INSERT into jos_trip_detail VALUES('$make[$i]','model[$i]','serials[$i]')");
        }


    }
    $msyql->close();

}



?>

<?php echo $output; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: `$msyql->` that in its own right is wrong.

Comment: `$databasename="jos_trip_detail"` is missing closure.

Comment: You should really declare the columns in your insert query. Even if it's not needed, it's recommended for your own sanity's sake and will reduce potential future bugs in case you add columns to your tables. Plus it makes it way more readable.

Comment: you're also only `count($make)`'ing one and not the others.

Comment: You're also missing the `$` in front of your variables in: `'model[$i]','serials[$i]'`

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting and display errors turned on ([Here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)). Then start fixing the errors one by one. There are waaaaay too many for us to be able to help.

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your help, I will move ahead with the recommended changes and come back when I am ready.

Answer (score -1):

You do have a syntax error. You should terminate the following line with a semicolon:

```
$databasename="jos_trip_detail"
```

becomes

```
$databasename="jos_trip_detail";
```

In addition to what was mentioned in the comments:

```
mysql_query("INSERT into jos_trip_detail VALUES('$make[$i]','model[$i]','serials[$i]')");
```

becomes

```
mysql_query("INSERT into jos_trip_detail VALUES('$make[$i]','$model[$i]','$serials[$i]')");
```